# Missing transactions with blockchain.info

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info

All of the quick send transfers I've made on blockchain.info do not show up in my blockchain.info history.  Furthermore, a person I have made a few quick send transaction with is claiming 0 confirmations on them.  And the transaction ids he recorded for these don't exist in blockchain.info's history of transactions.  These bitcoins have been deducted from my blockchain.info wallet, though.

1) Will these ever get confirmed?  If so, when?  If not, how do I get my bitcoins back?

2) Why aren't they showing up as transactions in blockchain.info?

Comment: Did you pay a fee for them?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not recall.  I used the "quick send" method in blockchain.info.